# How to connect my Unbuntu server via SSH with putty using key

Tags: server, ssh, putty

I install Ubuntu server 20.04 on vmware workstation  and tried to connect it without using password , in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I change

> 'passwordauthentification =no

did the "**

> sudo systemctl ssh restart"

** '  generate the key via ssh-keygen  copy the key into my notepad and save it as **key.ppk**  when I upload the  key with keygen i got this popup <

> No  supported authentification methods (server sent:publickey)

Because of that I had to et password again  not lose server access  , if anyone can guide me  for this please !

Comment: The key generated on the windows machine needs its id_rsa.pub contents copied into the Ubuntu's users /home/user_name/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Then it will connect without a password from windows to the Ubuntu machine with the windows machine using the private key associated with that .pub key file.

Answer (score 1):

The default `sshd_config` file has public key authentication enabled. So, once you disable password authentication by setting `PasswordAuthentication` to `no`, the SSH server will automatically use public key authentication.

If you didn't change it when generating the key pair using `ssh-keygen`, both the private and public key can be found in your home folder in `~/.ssh`

You will need to **convert the private key** (the one without the `.pub` extension) into a `.ppk` file (you can't simply rename it). Follow the instructions posted on https://www.dmit.io/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/10/How-to-convert-RSA-Private-Key-to-Putty-Private-Key-ppk.html to do so. (The page says "for use with WinSCP", but WinSCP and PuTTY share the same `.ppk` key format)

On the (Windows) client, you also need the PuTTY SSH agent to be running, and load the `key.ppk` file into the SSH agent. The SSH agent should be already installed along with PuTTY (you can find a shortcut to it in the Start menu), but in case you can't find it, open Windows Explorer and navigate to the folder where PuTTY is installed. The SSH agent executable is called `pageant.exe`, and once executed, you can access it from the system tray (the lower right corner of your desktop, near the clock).

Comment: I tried this method without uploading any key it give same popup like <No supported authentification methods (server sent:publickey)>

Comment: I just updated the answer to include instructions for private key conversion into `.ppk` format.

Comment: I will follow instructions right away sir thank you !

Comment: No problem, glad to help!